# Dynamic Collections vs Sharding

Tags: mongodb

I am writing an analytics app and each log will have custom data which I store in JSON as I don't know the fields in them.

Based on the user request, I index on few params for performance.

Eg: 
A can have {data: {price: 12.3}}
B can have {data : {price: 15, name: 'nice shirt'}}

A wants to get a list of all products with price less than 10. For this user, I want to index on price but since user B is not interested in price, I do not want his data to be indexed as this wasn't asked by B.

- I was planning to use a different collections for A and B and based on the user request, I index for that collection. Other users are not affected.
- I was told that sharding does almost the same thing but I'm not sure of the indexing. Is there a way to index per shard?

Comment: Nope, sharding won't do this. Use custom collections

Comment: Is the data in any way shared between A and B or does each user have a completely different dataset and there is no interaction between them? Or do you plan to have some use-cases which require data from more than one user?

Comment: there is no use-case where we need to share the data between A & B